# Package submission to CRAN, avoiding the print() or cat() functions

Tags: r, package, cran

I'm developping an R package for my lab colleagues, who are not familiar with R.
The goal of the package is to help casual R users to create advanced plots and to identify crucial data preparation steps.

To do so, my code check if the inputs variables are ok for the analyses. If yes or no, a corresponding summary messages is printed directly in the console. Like : "Ok for plots" or "Wrong factor choice : the factor XX is only defined by 1 modality". Initialy I used the function `print()`

When I submit the package to CRAN, everything is good but the messages printed. CRAN members say :

> "It is more R like to generate objects that can be used to extract the
> information a user is interested in, and then print() that object.
> Instead of print()/cat() rather use message()/warning()  or
> if(verbose)cat(..) (or maybe stop()) if you really have to write text
> to the console. (except for print, summary, interactive functions)"

I tried to overcome this problem by changing `print()` to `cat()` or `message()` when it was possible. But I still get the same reviewing.

So yes, I could remove thoses messages, but this is not what I want to do. Moreover, casual R users may prefer message displaying in the console rather than finding the same information in LIST or objects.

Any idea how to overcome this issue ?
Thx

Comment: If the package is solely for your lab colleagues, why do you _need_ to submit it to CRAN?

Comment: In what cases do you need to use `print` or `cat`? It's better to use `warning` or `message` in most cases if you are giving feedback. It's not clear why you can't make the switch in all cases.

Comment: For warnings messages, i.e when data inputs limit the rest of code, I get it 100% and I already changed the cat() to warnings(). However, for non error messages, I prefer the cat() function because message() display red text in console. If there is no other options, I will change the cat() to message().

Comment: Red text in the console? I don't see that ... perhaps because I'm in emacs/ess and not RStudio. Look into `cli` or `crayon` or one of the other console-coloring utilities that the RStudio company uses in their IDE, it's possible you can override (even temporarily) the coloring. I'm with MrFlick, a package should really never use `cat` to send a message to the console; I've run into packages that do that, and me having to use `capture.output` in order to _fix_ or _work around_ their problems is frustrating.